# iOS Game Center not giving push notification to my app only gives badge notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, notifications

I am developing a turn based game between two opponents with Game center in iOS. I followed this tutorial step by step to do so http://www.raywenderlich.com/5480/beginning-turn-based-gaming-with-ios-5-part-1. Everything works Fine but only Push notification. When I call this method **endTurnWithNextParticipant** Push notification doesn't come in notification center of other player. However when i click on Game center app(not my app) a badge notification appears on my app.

Problem
1) Push notification doesn't come but badge notification comes to my app when i click on Game center app

Irony is that 
Push notification starts coming and every thing works fine if I use this bundle id as my project id **com.razeware.spinningyarn**. This bundle id is was in Tutorial project that i followed in above provided link.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: did you find any solution for that...i have the same problem

Comment: No manjit  i didn't. Actually that project is on hold for now and I am not working on that. Did you find any solution. I think probably when you put ur application Live on itunes then everything should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply i hope so the notification will fix when app get live because i don't find any solution for the that.